# Parsing through multiple result pages using python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am trying to parse a library website to obtain information from a specific publisher. Here is the link to the website.

http://hollis.harvard.edu/?q=publisher:%22sonzogno%22+ex-Everything-7.0:%221700-1943%22+

So far by using beautiful soup, I can grab data that I need from this page. The problem being my script grabs only the first 25 entries ( a single pages worth) from the the entire result set which has a lot more.

What am I missing here?

Here is the small snippet of code.

```
def url_parse(name):
```

if(name == " "):
    print 'Invalid Error'
  else:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(name)
    html_doc = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
    print soup.title
    print soup.find_all("a",{"class":"classiclink"})
    #print soup.find("a",{"class":"classiclink"})
    aleph_li = [] # creates and emptylist
    aleph_li = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"classiclink"})

After this I plan to use the information available in these tags.So far like you said, I can grab only 25 of them.

I am unable to iterate through each page, as the url(containing some sort of query) doesn't seem to have any page information. I am not sure how make recurring requests to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: the first page only contains 25, you have to crawl the other ones too. We can't tell you what you are missing unless we see some code.

Comment: @root, I have updated the question.Hopefully, it makes my problem clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this won't be so hard:

If you look at the request to get other page, which is called `result.ashx`, you can see the following parameters:

```
inlibrary:false
noext:false
debug:
lastquery:publisher:"sonzogno" ex-Everything-7.0:"1700-1943"
lsi:user
uilang:en
searchmode:assoc
hardsort:def
skin:harvard
rctx:AAMAAAABAAAAAwAAABJ/AAAHaGFydmFyZDJwdWJsaXNoZXI6InNvbnpvZ25vIiBleC1FdmVyeXRoaW5nLTcuMDoiMTcwMC0xOTQzIjJwdWJsaXNoZXI6InNvbnpvZ25vIiBleC1FdmVyeXRoaW5nLTcuMDoiMTcwMC0xOTQzIhJzb256b2dubyAxNzAwLTE5NDMAAAAAA25hdgR1c2VyAAAAA2RlZgpyZXN1bHRsaXN0BWFzc29jBQAAAAAAAAACZW4AAP////9AEAAAAAAAAAIAAAAGY19vdmVyATEEaV9mawAAAAAA
c_over:1
curpage:3
concept:sonzogno 1700-1943
branch:
ref:
i_fk:
mxdk:-1
q:publisher:"sonzogno" ex-Everything-7.0:"1700-1943"
si:user
cs:resultlist
cmd:nav
```

So try to add a parameter `curpage` in your own request. It's likely that you're going to have to use a loop to go through all the results but this seems very doable:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({"curpage": NUMBER})
urllib2.urlopen(YOUR_PAGE, params)
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to have python call each page in sequence. it's not smart enough to know you want to go through all the pages.

if you ARE calling all the pages, you should be parsing your needed results to an output file of some form, either a .pkl file that you can later process via python, or a .txt file if you feel that's all you need. you could be running into a memory overflow, if the datasets you're working with are obnoxiously long.

even if you're not yet calling all the pages, it'd be smart to stream your output data into a .pkl file for processing into usable form at the end.

Answer (score 0):

HOLLIS has a [JSON API](http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/systems/webservices/lookup-userguide/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=lookup-userguide&file=search_hollis.html) in Beta.  Its results include links to the next pages.  This might be a lot easier to use.